# Why ASP.Net Core 7.0 Web API showing as Connection refused?

Tags: asp.net-core

I am new to asp.net core 7.0.

I am working on the Web Api. However I created one controller with [ApiController] decoration.

In the launchSettings.json file it shows port number as 14023 as shown below :-

```
"iisSettings": {
  "windowsAuthentication": false,
  "anonymousAuthentication": true,
  "iisExpress": {
    "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:14023",
    "sslPort": 44381
  }
```

Means that my Web API will be pointing to http://localhost:14023

However when I run the application and navigate to http://localhost:14023
it shows below error :

> This site can’t be reached
>
> localhost refused to connect.
>
> ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

And when I hit the same API URL through Postman then below error coming :-

**Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:14023**

Initially I thought that it could be related to CORS so I added below code in Program.cs file :-

```
builder.Services.AddCors();

app.UseCors(options =>
options.AllowAnyOrigin()
.AllowAnyMethod()
.AllowAnyHeader()
);
```

Can anyone help me on this?

I am stuck. Even I googled but did not find any suitable answer.

Comment: Does the web server run at all? IIS Express is a development web server that's started by Visual Studio when you start debugging your application and shuts down when you stop

Comment: Yes. It runs.. I added only web api controller.

Comment: Are you sure the project starts with iisExpress  instead of kestrel  or anything else?